# how to animate image which is behind one image after hover that image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

basic html below i have given the basic html code.I am beginner in web development.
Here i am trying to first animate bottom class image when it hovers.Then after that animation i want to display another image and simultaneously apply bouncing effect to that image i have completed both the effects seperately.But dont know how to link that second image animation with the first one? suggest solution.

```
    < div id="cf">
        < img class="top" src="/home/animesh/Downloads/index.jpeg"/>
        <img class="bottom" src="/home/animesh/Downloads/logo.jpg"/>    
    </div>
```

css code:

```
    <style>
    #cf img.top
    {
         height:170px;
         width:170px;
         margin-left:10px;
         margin-top:10px;
    }
    #cf img.bottom
    {
         height:170px;
         width:170px;
         margin-left:10px;
         margin-top:10px;
         background:black;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes cf
    {
         5%
         {
               box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px #ffe6e6;
         }
         15%
         {
               box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 2px #ff8080;
          }
          25%
          {
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px #ff3333;
          }
          35%
          {
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 2px #e60000;
          }
          75%
          {
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px #cc0000;    
          }
          85%
          {
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 2px #ff3333;
          }
          95%
          {
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px #ff9999;
          }
          100%
          {
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 2px #ffffff;
          }
    }
    @keyframes cf {
          5%
          {
               box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px #ffe6e6;
          }
          15%
          {
               box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 2px #ff8080;
          }
          25%
          {
               box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px #ff3333;
          }
          35%
          {
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 2px #e60000;
           }
          50%
         {
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 2px #990000;
           }
          75%
          {
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px #cc0000;    
          }
          85%
          {
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 2px #ff3333;
          } 
          95%
           {
                 box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px #ff9999;
           }
          100%
          {
                 box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 2px #ffffff;
          }
    }
    @keyframes bounce {
            0%, 20%, 60%, 100% {
           -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
            }

            40% {
               -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
               transform: translateY(-20px);
             }

            80% {
                -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
                 transform: translateY(-10px);
             }
         }
   #cf img {
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
         -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
     }

     #cf img.bottom:hover {
             opacity:0;
             animation-name:cf;
             animation-duration:1s;
             -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
             animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            }
      #cf img.top:hover{
              animation-name:bounce;
              animation-duration:1s;
           }

    </style>
```

Comment: I would try setting the background-image property in your css.

Comment: yeah bt that will only change the image but how you will link animation bounce code assiciated with it?

Comment: hey bro got the ans thanx by the way for response!!!!

Comment: post and answer your question if its closed

Comment: i have used nth-child concept animation chaining..